# How can I list all editors of a WordPress page, including those who edited (saved page) without creating a proper revision?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to display a list of the people who have authored AND edited a page in Wordpress, not just the people who have authored revisions.  `the_modified_author()` gives me the name of the person who last saved the page.  [birgire](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/26350/birgire) suggested this code to get the list of all editors, but it seems to only show the authors of the original post and all revisions, and doesn't include the names of those who saved a change that wasn't actually a revision:

```
function get_the_modified_authors_wpse_99226(){
global $wpdb;
$authors = array();
$results = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT post_author FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE (post_type = '%s' AND ID = %d) OR (post_type = 'revision' AND post_parent = %d) GROUP BY post_author", get_post_type( get_the_ID() ), get_the_ID(), get_the_ID() ) );
foreach($results as $row){
      $authors[] =  get_the_author_meta('display_name', $row->post_author );
}
return implode(", ", $authors);
}
```

Sometimes people edit a page (for example, they make an edit to a custom field) and then update the post.  When that happens, they would be listed under `the_modified_author()` but would not be considered an author of a revision.

What I need is a combined list of both revision authors AND those people who have edited (saved) the page without creating a revision.  Sort of like the function for modified_author but without the `'_edit_last', true` part.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code :

```
$revisions = $wpdb->get_results("select * from {$wpdb->posts} where post_parent={$post_id} and post_type='revision'")
```

You may need to do some change according to your need.